# Parsing XML Object

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file (part of shown) which I'm using simplexml_load_file in PHP to parse. I'm trying to get the api:email-address element.

```
<entry>
<id>13624</id>
<updated>2023-07-12T18:56:22.05+01:00</updated>
<link type="application/atom+xml" rel="alternate" href="https://test.com" />
<title>SOMEONE, A Mr</title>
<content type="xhtml">
<api:object category="user" id="13624" proprietary-id="test" authenticating-authority="test"     `your text``your text`username="test" last-affected-when="2023-07-12T18:56:22.05+01:00" last-modified-when="2023-05-10T18:06:55.66+01:00" href="https://13624" created-when="2016-08-09T11:52:25.353+01:00" type-id="1" type-display-name="Person" type="person"><!-- User type 1 is "person" -->
    <api:ever-approved>true</api:ever-approved>
    <api:privacy-level>Public</api:privacy-level>
    <api:privacy-level-locked>false</api:privacy-level-locked>
    <api:is-public>true</api:is-public>
    <api:allow-type-switching>true</api:allow-type-switching>
    <api:is-current-staff>true</api:is-current-staff>
    <api:is-academic>false</api:is-academic>
    <api:is-student>false</api:is-student>
    <api:is-login-allowed>true</api:is-login-allowed>
    <api:title>Mr</api:title>
    <api:initials>AS</api:initials>
    <api:last-name>SOMEONE</api:last-name>
    <api:first-name>ANDREW</api:first-name>
    <api:email-address>myemail@somewhere.com</api:email-address>
</api:object>
</entry>
```

I can get the initial elements (i.e. ID) using:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
$value = $entry->id;
print_r($value);
}
```

but I've tried different ways to get the api:email-address element but am stuck!

Any help appreciated.